# Nginx: escape non-alphanumeric characters in rewrite

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am migrating from Apache to Nginx, and I need a way to convert Apache's rewrite flag [B].

The [B] flag escapes all non-alphanumeric characters before applying rewrite transformation.
So for example

```
x & y/z
```

will be converted to

```
x%20%26%20y%2Fz
```

Is there a way to do this in Nginx? Examples I've found online only remove those characters, but I need a way to convert them.

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx provides some default functionality for that.
You can use `ngx.escape_uri` and `ngx.unescape_uri` or `ngx.encode_args` and `ngx.decode_args` with some lua to encode decode. [Here are docs](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#ngxescape_uri)

In case you need a custom solution, either custom code a lua module for that task or maybe something like this [lua module](https://github.com/TiagoDanin/htmlEntities-for-lua) to transform special characters

Steps are:

1. Install lua-rocks and the html-entities lib

```
apt-get install luarocks
luarocks install html-entities
```

2. html-entites lib will convert every character to html entity. So you should filter characters that you need. In this example I am converting all characters that are not basic english letters. Create a file mymodule.lua

```
htmlEntities = require('htmlEntities')

local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.convert(string)
    return string:gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", function(c) return htmlEntities.encode(c) end)
end

return mymodule
```

3. In nginx.conf
   specify lua path. This will load all lua files inside path2 folder

```
http {
    lua_package_path "/path1/path2/?.lua;;";
    ...
```

and to use that module you can use *_by_lua directives. For example in location

```
set_by_lua $escape "return require('mymodule').convert(ngx.var.name);" $name;
```

Comment: The ngx.escape_uri docs are very confusing to be thrown at, how do you use this? I don't even know what it is. And trying your numbered steps just gets me `$ sudo nginx -t` ->
`nginx: [emerg] unknown "name" variable 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`. 

Thank you for the help though, this is still better than anything else I've found so far to solve the issue of replicating the [B] and [NE] apache rewrite flags in nginx.